# align span icon block on input field

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a login form with block icons before the input fields.

```
@import url(http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css);
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);

[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}

#login {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 300px;
    background: #999;
    padding: 50px;
}

#login p {
    line-height: 50px;
}

#login p span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
} 

#login p input { 
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    padding: 3px; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    background: #fdfdfd;
}
```

html

```
<div id="login">
       <p><span class="fontawesome-user"></span><input type="text" placeholder="Username"></p>
       <p><span class="fontawesome-lock"></span><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I can not precisely align the block (span) icon with the input field. How could I do this? thanks

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cn36g/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to vertical-align the inline-block elements, eg :

```
#login p > * {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Forked Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJH5P/)